# URL rewriting : redirect ugly url to clean url

Tags: .htaccess

In my .htaccess file, I use this rule to clean urls (this works) :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

But all my pages are duplicated : "ugly urls" are still available. That is a problem. I searched on the web how to redirect "ugly urls" to "cleaned urls" but I didn't find any solution.

An example is often usefull. I want `index.php?page=about` to be directly redirected to `about.html`.

Could someone help me ? I want to solve this and understand how to do it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For next viewers, best is to implement and use a php router.